# Receber por Parametro e Manipular uma LISTA de Objeto Genérico

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

Preciso receber por parâmetro uma Lista de Objeto *Genérico* e manipular, apesar de pesquisar não entendi certo como fazer.

Exemplo:

```
public class Funcionario
{
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public string Nome {get; set;}
    public DateTime DataContrato {get; set;}
}

public class Professor
{
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public string Nome {get; set;}
    public bool IsAtivo {get; set;}
}

public void Reload(List<objeto> GridListaObjeto, int qtde)
{
    foreach (var obj in GridListaObjeto)
    {
        string sId = obj.Id;
        string sNome = obj.Nome;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classe `List<T>` é implementada de forma genérica.
Onde `T` a classe da qual você quer criar a lista.

Por exemplo, para usar uma lista de professores, seu método deve receber como parâmetro um `List<Professor> professores`.
Ficaria assim:

```
public void Reload(List<Professor> professores, int qtde)
{
    foreach(Professor p in professores)
    {
        string sId = p.Id;
        string sNome = p.Nome;
    }
}
```

Para `Aluno` seria a mesma coisa, mudaria apenas o tipo.

Agora, se no seu caso você realmente recebe uma `List<Object>`, para acessar as propriedades `Id` e `Nome`, você precisa garantir que a instância do objeto do tipo Object seja dos tipos `Professor` ou `Aluno`.
Para isso você pode usar o `is`. Veja:

```
public void Reload(List<Object> objects, int qtde)
{
    if(objects[0] is Professor) 
    {
        foreach(Object obj in objects)
        {
            Professor p = (Professor) obj;
            string sId = p.Id;
            string sNome = p.Nome;
        }
    }
}
```

É claro que existem implementações mais "elegantes", mas para fins didáticos, é isso aí hehe.
Novamente, para `Aluno` é a mesma coisa, só alterar o tipo de `Professor` para `Aluno`.

Comment: Tem como instanciar no main uma lista do tipo genérica e inicializa-la dentro do método?